# PCRE Regex to Erlang Regex

Tags: regex, erlang

I would like to ask how to convert PCRE based regex into ERLANG regex. I am currently testing MyDLP solution, which uses PCRE through Erlang’s re library. However I am not able to write such an example:

```
[3-6][0-9]{2}[0,1][0-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}
```

How should I translate this? any advice is welcome..

My test numbers: 49102050805

Comment: Have you tried running this regex? The syntax looks correct to me. Note that `[0,1]` will match `0` or `,` or `1`. If you want `0` or `1` it should be `[01]`.

Comment: Yes, in Perl PCRE this regex works good, however I would need to rewrite this in Erlang to match the same pattern it should be something like:
re:run("String", "[3-6][0-9]{2}[0,1][0-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}"), however mydlp does not accept it

Comment: @Bandymi can you post a sample of your code either here or on [tio.run](https://tio.run/#erlang-escript) (then share link back here)?

Comment: Your code works for me: `1> re:run("30000000000", "[3-6][0-9]{2}[0,1][0-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}"). => {match,[{0,11}]}`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
1> String = "49102050805".
"49102050805"
2> re:run(String, "[3-6][0-9]{2}[0,1][0-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}").       
{match,[{0,11}]}
```